# How to use if function in shell scripts?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I need to use if function to filter out required files only when using SFTP to copy files to my server from a remote server. Here is my try to get the all data inside `/filesnew`.

```
#!/bin/bash


files=`sshpass -p 'XXX' sftp -P 2222 User1@10.18.90.12<<EOF
cd /filesnew
ls
EOF`

files=`echo $files|sed "s/.*sftp> ls//"`



(
  echo cd /filesnew
  for file in $files; do
    echo get $file /data/processedfiles/$file
  done
) |sshpass -p 'XXX' sftp -P 2222 User1@10.18.90.12
```

I need to filter out the files which are starting with `"USER"`.

```
ex:
If($files==*USER*) then
echo get $file /data/processedfiles/$file
```

Can someone show me how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use spaces around operators. Those are all **arguments** for commands and spaces separate them.

"If" is spelled `if` (lowercase) in Bash.

Testing a condition is done with `[`...`]` in Bash, not with `(`...`)`.

Filtering is not comparison. Those are completely different operations. Use `grep`:

```
... | grep -E -v '^USER'
```

See: `man grep`